# clear all the entries from a table with php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to clear all the entries from one table in MySQL with php
I tried this:

```
<?php
// Create connection
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbName");

// Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }    

    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE tableName";
    mysqli_query($sql);
?>
```

but it didn't work. why?

Comment: does it give any error ?

Comment: Could you give some details about the error messages provided by either PHP of MySQL?

Comment: and moreover, in half code you are using `mysqli` and then `mysql`, why ??

Comment: You are using mysqli functions and mysql functions interchangeably, or use the mysql functions or use the mysqli functions

Comment: May be you do not have permission to run this.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it looks like a mysqli issue. Just make sure you have DROP permission if all else fails.

Comment: @DavidHoude: but why? it could have been one of the reasons as well.. your answer was *not* the worst one anyway :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a typo. You used `mysql_query()` instead of `mysqli_query()`. Change

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

to:

```
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Also note that the param lists of both functions differ. `mysqli_expects()` a connection handle as it's first param.

Comment: @hek2mgl: it doesn't work.
says: Invocation parameter types are not compatible with declared.

Answer (score 2):

After creating a connection using "mysqli", you are trying to delete all the records in "dbName" using mysql_query.

Change the code to something like,

```
<?php
    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbName");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }    
    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE tableName";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
?>
```

See if this works and let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly check for any error messages that may give a clue, there are some restrictions that can prevent TRUNCATE from working.  Also ensure it's not a typo with the mysql/mysqli functions as in your question.

If the table isn't huge, or performance isn't critical then simply try:

```
$sql = "DELETE * FROM tableName";
```

Comment: performance is not the only difference between delete and truncate